# Minimize many scalar functions

Tags: python, scipy, minimization

In python, I'd like to minimize hundreds of thousands of scalar valued functions. Is there a faster way than a for-loop over a `def` of the objective function and a call to `scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar`? Basically a vectorized version, where I could give a function `foo` and a 2D numpy array where each row is given as extra data to the objective function.

Comment: If i understand your task correctly, you will find some discussion [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8354). But the question itself also feels quite sparse in it's details.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It looks like it's not possible then. Hopefully the PR will help.

Comment: Very good question. Eagerly searching for answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible currently in scipy, without using a workaround like multiprecessing, threads, or converting the many one dimensional problems to a giant multidimensional one. There is however [a pull request](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/8357) currently open to adress this.

Comment: Has the pull request been merged?